# How does the flag moderating process work?

Tags: support, flags, moderator-tools, 10k-tools

I am on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=flags&daterange=) to *moderate* (not sure if it's correct word for this) the flags. I find there the following information:

> #### What is this?
>
> It's a list of posts that other community members have flagged as needing attention. What do you think we should do with them? **Cast your own flags and close votes** to determine what happens to these posts.

Randomly, I take the first flagged post:

> [image]

There is a button <kbd>flag or disagree...</kbd>. When I click on it a popup appears:

> [image]

After I choose an option and I click <kbd>Flag Answer</kbd> button, what happens?

It looks for me like a recursive thing: *are we moderating flags by flagging them?*

Comment: You're always flagging posts, not flags. Even the "invalid flag" thing is "this post has invalid flags".

Comment: @Mat I am confused... What will happen with the post after *x* useful flags? What is the *x* value?

Comment: Apart from SPAM/offensive flags (and some comment flags), nothing happens to the post automatically. The additional flags are used to prioritize things for moderators.

Comment: @Mat So, are all flagged posts moderated by `♦` real moderators? I understand that they are just reordered by `+10k` users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This confused me too.

Basically, you are "validating" flags by piling on your own flags (which pushes them up in the mod queue). Flag pile-on is not too helpful, though, you should always try to vote to close/delete the posts if you feel it necessary and you have the privilege to do so.

If you feel that a flag is *invalid*, flag the post with "invalid flags".

Comment: I understand that all flagged posts are moderated by `♦ moderators` and the posts are just reordered by `+10k` users. Right?

Comment: @イオニカビザウ No, if you vote to delete or close, and enough other 10ks do the same, the post gets dealt with.